# How to get the cursor position in TextInput and the content after the cursor position?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to write a component which can edit an article for words input and insert images. I use TextInput for words input. If I want to insert an image in the middle of the text, I will generate an Image component and an new TextInput after the Image. But I don't know how to get the cursor position and content after the cursor.
Anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

`<TextInput>`  has `onSelectionChange` which fires with `{ nativeEvent:{ start:number, end:number } }`. It updates whenever cursor position changes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Noitidart points to the right direction

> `<TextInput>`  has `onSelectionChange` which fires with `{ nativeEvent:{ start:number, end:number } }`. It updates whenever cursor position changes.

However, it's useful to note that as of RN 0.61, `onSelectionChange` fires with `{ nativeEvent: { selection: { start:number, end:number } }, text: string }`.

Comment: Good point! A selection object contains them.